# On proving events have nonempty intersection if the sum of their complement is smaller than 1

Tags: probability

Suppose for Events $A_1, A_2,\ldots,A_n$ we have that:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {\mathbb P}(A^{c}_i) < 1 $$

Does this imply:

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} A_i \neq \emptyset $$

I think it does, but I couldn't manage to prove it, anybody please give some hints! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: contrapositive.

Comment: "Indepedent" is not the word you want in the title.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know which is the correct terminology here

Comment: I edited it to "have nonempty intersection".  "Independent" means [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_events).

Answer (score 3):

Assume:

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} A_i = \emptyset $$

Then:

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i^c = \Omega $$

$$1=P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i^c\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i^c)$$

Comment: Thanks, it really helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

Start with n = 2. Suppose that 
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^2 {\mathbb P}(A^{c}_i) = 1$$

We also know that

$$P(A_1^c \cup A_2^c)=P(A_1^c)+P(A_2^c)-P(A_1^c \cap A_2^c) $$

Since probability is bounded at 1, it is clear that $P(A_1^c \cap A_2^c)$ must equal 0.

By De Morgan's laws, we know that

$$P(A_1^c \cap A_2^c) = P((A_1 \cup A_2)^c)$$

Since

$$P((A_1 \cup A_2)^c) = 0$$

Then

$$P(A_1 \cup A_2) = 1$$

From here,

$$P(A_1 \cup A_2) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) - P(A_1 \cap A_2)$$
$$1 = P(A_1) + P(A_2) - P(A_1 \cap A_2)$$
$$1 = (1 - P(A_1^c)) + (1 - P(A_2^c)) - P(A_1 \cap A_2)$$
$$1 = 2 - [P(A_1^c) + P(A_2^c)] - P(A_1 \cap A_2)$$

From the last equation we can see that if, as we first conjectured, $P(A_1^c) + P(A_2^c) = 1$, then $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 0$. Otherwise, in order for the equality to be satisfied, $P(A_1 \cap A_2)$ must be greater than 0.

Now try to extend this to n > 2 and your proof will be complete.